# Foreach(Powershell) doesn't seems to be working properly

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell scripting. I'm trying to retrieve domain user info, like account info, password expired/lockout info, DL groups, mailbox, security groups (of which user is a member of) etc in a GUI box.

I'm able to get account/password info, however, cannot get group membership info in a textbox. I'm only getting the first group from group membership.
Here is a code:

```
$userinfo = (Get-aduser $user -Properties *)

"============================================================================================================"
"`t `t `t `t `t `t ACCOUNT DETAILS" 
"============================================================================================================"
$userinfo | fl DisplayName, EmailAddress, Enabled, Title, @{n="Manager";e={(Get-aduser -id $_.manager).name}},Department,@{n="Extension";e={$_.IPphone}}, TelephoneNumber, Created, Modified, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName,@{n="Country";e={$_.co}}, Office, msExchWhenMailboxCreated   
"============================================================================================================"
"`t `t `t `t `t  PASSWORD/LOCKOUT DETAILS" 
"============================================================================================================"
$userinfo | fl LockedOut, PasswordExpired, lockoutTime, LastLogonDate , LastBadPasswordAttempt, PasswordLastSet, @{Name="Password Expires in (days)";Expression={(new-timespan -start $EndDate -end ([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-aduser $user -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))).Days}}
"============================================================================================================"
"`t `t `t `t `t  Distribution Groups (AD)" 
"============================================================================================================"
$userinfo.memberof  | %{(get-adgroup -id $_ -Properties:groupcategory| ?{$_.groupcategory -match "Distribution" }).name}
```

And here is the output textbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TomL.png)

Foreach doesn't seem to be working properly while showing the result in a textbox. Let me know if you require more info.

Comment: Am I wrong or don't you fill in your variable `$miduser`? If so `$miduser.memberof` is empty and therefor `Foreach-Object` has nothing to work with, right?

Comment: @Olaf, it would be $userinfo instead of $miduser. It works fine when I run it on console or export to csv, but not in textbox.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler,  I'm not using output from format-list. Instead I'm using memberof property of an object. Same code works fine while running on ise or exporting to csv but not on textbox of windows form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userinfo = (Get-aduser $user -Properties *)

"============================================================================================================"
"`t `t `t `t `t `t ACCOUNT DETAILS" 
"============================================================================================================"
$userinfo | fl DisplayName, EmailAddress, Enabled, Title, @{n="Manager";e={(Get-aduser -id $_.manager).name}},Department,@{n="Extension";e={$_.IPphone}}, TelephoneNumber, Created, Modified, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName,@{n="Country";e={$_.co}}, Office, msExchWhenMailboxCreated   
"============================================================================================================"
"`t `t `t `t `t  PASSWORD/LOCKOUT DETAILS" 
"============================================================================================================"
$userinfo | fl LockedOut, PasswordExpired, lockoutTime, LastLogonDate , LastBadPasswordAttempt, PasswordLastSet, @{Name="Password Expires in (days)";Expression={(new-timespan -start $EndDate -end ([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-aduser $user -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))).Days}}
"============================================================================================================"
"`t `t `t `t `t  Distribution Groups (AD)" 
"============================================================================================================"
($userinfo.memberof | foreach { Get-ADGroup $_ } | Where {$_.GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"}).Name | FL
```

The last line is now using the `$userinfo` object you created in the first line for the user's memberships and making the appropriate `Where` comparison.

If you did indeed mean to use `$miduser` in the last line, one reason it may not work is that the resulting properties for the `Where` statement are case-sensitive. I'm not sure why you would have received only a single result and not the rest.

Comment: Adam, sorry it is $userinfo.memberof not $miduser.memberof.

Comment: I've provided an answer

Comment: No, it is still the same.

Comment: Add ` | FL` to the end of the line

Comment: I've found one workaround. Actually I was using this code (containing Foreach) in Try and Catch statement which was not giving desired output in Textbox. Now I'm using If and Else which works fine. Next time I'll share whole code. Thanks :)